# dompdf not creating pdf correctly

Tags: html, pdf, dompdf

I'm using dompdf to try and convert html into a pdf file. The file was created no problem but when I tried to open the file, it was corrupt. When I opened the file in notepad, I could see it was just the raw html. So it hadn't converted anything at all, it had just put it in a file with an extension of pdf.

Here is my code:

```
include_once '/files/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php';
$files = glob("/files/dompdf/include/*.php");
foreach($files as $file) include_once($file);

ob_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>
            Title
        </title>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div><p>Hello World</p></div>
    </body>

</html>

<?php
$html = ob_get_clean();

$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("sample.pdf");
```

This just grabs the html exactly as it is written here and saves it as sample.pdf but its not a proper pdf file. Am I missing something?

Comment: FYI, unless you have disabled the autoloader you shouldn't need lines 2 - 3. dompdf sets up an autoloader to fetch the files as needed.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by stripping slashes. This is the updated:

```
$html = ob_get_clean();

if ( get_magic_quotes_gpc() )
    $html = stripslashes($html);

$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("sample.pdf");
```

Comment: I'm not sure why adding `stripslashes()` would fix your issue, but if that seems to do it ...